# Test BackboneJS REST API with local data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, backbone.js

I have a BackboneJS Model/Collection as below;

```
var PersonInfo = BaseModel.extend({
    idAttribute: "PersonInfoId",
    urlRoot: "api/outline/",
    defaults: {
        "name": null,
        "class": null
    }
});


var PersonInfoCollection = BaseCollection.extend({
    url: "api/outline/",
    model: PersonInfo
});
```

Now I have a grid which gets populated with response/data from backend (REST call)
So I say;

```
var personInfoCollection = new PersonInfoCollection();
myGrid.backboneRegColl(personInfoCollection);
```

Also my method is defined as;

```
Grid.prototype.backboneRegColl = function(collection, parameters) {
            var self = this;
             collection.setServerParameters(pars);

                collection.bind("dataReady", function(data) {
                    //Clear the grid data
                    self.clear();
                    //Get data from collection
                    var data = collection.toJSON();
                    //Render data from collection
                    self.renderData(data);
                });
}
```

Also renderData is defined as below;

```
Grid.prototype.renderData = function(data) {

            var self = this;

            //Empty data rows
            this.el.find("tbody").empty();
            //get data from grid storage
            var dataToRender = this.data;

            //Override data to render from arguments
            if(data != undefined) {
                dataToRender = data;
            }
            if(dataToRender.length && ! $.isArray(dataToRender)) {
                dataToRender = dataToRender.toArray();
            }
            //If the dataToRender is an array
            if($.isArray(dataToRender)) {
                //If its an empty array
                //XXX
                if(dataToRender.length === 0) {
                    //Show no records message
                    _createEmptyRecordsMessage.call(this);
                }
                else {
                    //Render each row
                    $.each(dataToRender, function(index, dataRow) {
                        $frag.append(_createDataRow.call(self, dataRow));
                    });
                    $("tbody", this.el).append($frag);
                }
            }
            //If the dataToRender is null, undefined or not an array
            else {
                //Show no records message
                _createEmptyRecordsMessage.call(this);
            }

            //Resize is called to make sure header and data table widths are aligned
            this._resize();

            function _createDataRow(data) {
                var tr = $("<tr>").attr("tabIndex","-1"),
                self = this;

                //For each column in column definitions
                $(this.cols).each(function(index, column){
                    //Create a cell
                    var cell = $("<td>");
                    var dataValue = $("<div>").html("-");
                    if($.isFunction(column.renderer)) {
                        //Call the renderer and place the returned html|string into the data container 
                        dataValue.html(column.renderer.call(data, $.extend(true, {}, column)));
                    }
                    else if(data[column.id] !== undefined && data[column.id] !== null) {
                        //Set the text of the data container to the data
                        dataValue.html(data[column.id]).attr('title', data[column.id]);
                    }

                    cell.append(dataValue);

                    tr.append(cell);
                });

                //store the data for the row in the html row
                tr.data(data);

                return tr;
            }
        }
```

Now my question is I do not have the REST API ready...So how do I test that the grid gets populated correctly, by using local JSON data ?

Comment: why not simply hardcode all sample data into your code

Comment: I need to test using static Backbone model/collection data

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/huffingtonpost/backbone-fixtures, maybe it could help you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could try to use [reset](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset) to do the dummy data testing.

Reset function can help you replace a collection with a new one and trigger a 'reset' event. We can use it to assign a dummy data for testing.

Try to register a 'reset' event listener on the collection obj:

```
Grid.prototype.backboneRegColl = function(collection, parameters) {
    var self = this;
    collection.setServerParameters(pars);

    collection.bind("reset dataReady", function(data) {
      //Clear the grid data
      self.clear();
      //Get data from collection
      var data = collection.toJSON();
      //Render data from collection
      self.renderData(data);
    });
}
```

Then assign a dummy data to collection by invoking reset function. (please make sure the data strcture is correct)

```
personalInfoCollection.reset([{id:1,name:"Jimmy",tel:"123456"},{id:2,name:"Deemon",tel:"222222"}]);
```

The view will be rendered properly after the 'reset' event is being triggered.